Failure to verify dex file
dex2oatd E 06-19 11:52:37 1358970 1358970 oat_writer.cc:3217] Failed to verify /system/framework/xxx-xxx.jar: Failure to verify dex file '/system/framework/xxx-xxx.jar': Duplicate map section of type f000
java_import {
name: "prebuilt-xxx-xxx",
jars: ["cm_prebuilts/xxx-xxx.jar"],
}
java_library {
name: "xxx-xxx",
static_libs: [
"prebuilt-xxx-xxx",
],
installable: true,
}
PRODUCT_BOOT_JARS += xxx-xxx
out/target/product/qssi_64/system/framework/xxx-xxx.jar
If the resource is a jar package, cannot the generated jar be placed in the bootclasspath？
dex2oatd E 06-19 11:52:37 1358970 1358970 oat_writer.cc:3217] Failed to verify /system/framework/xxx-xxx.jar: Failure to verify dex file '/system/framework/xxx-xxx.jar': Duplicate map section of type f000
dex2oatd I 06-19 11:52:37 1358970 1358970 dex2oat.cc:2896] dex2oat took 568.564ms (306.860ms cpu) (threads: 16)
ERROR: Dex2oat failed to compile a boot image.It is likely that the boot classpath is inconsistent.Rebuild with ART_BOOT_IMAGE_EXTRA_ARGS="--runtime-arg -verbose:verifier" to see verification errors.

Stackoverflow is a Q&A site, so please take your time and formulate a question and not just jump an error log here.
